# How to output SSH commands that are being sent to a server

Tags: ssh, scripting, output, tee

I have a script that connect to a Network device. It runs some commands and basically I want to output the SSH commands that are being executed.

To make myself clearer, I connect to one device, execute the commands "execute fmscript showlog " and it shows some output.
The thing is in the log file where the output is redirected, I can't see the "execute fmscript etc." command printed into the file, just the results.

```
sshpass -p 12345678 ssh admin@10.1.1.1 'execute fmscript showlog FG300D-1' > output.txt
```

And this is the result:

```
FMG-VM64-KVM # 

Starting log (Run on device)

FG300D-1 $  fnsysctl ps -A
PID       UID     GID     STATE   CMD
```

On the first line you can see FMG-VM64#
What I want to see is "FMG-VM64#execute fmscript showlog FG300D-1".

Any way of doing this? I tried with tee with no success.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about

```
CMD='execute fmscript showlog FG300D-1'
echo $CMD > output.txt
sshpass -p 12345678 ssh admin@10.1.1.1 "$CMD" >> output.txt
```